# Xarray won't decode times from netCDF file with decode_cf=False, even if decode_times=True

Tags: python, datetime, netcdf, python-xarray

I have some netCDF files similar to below. Opening them with `decode_cf=True` converts most of my byte and int variables to floats for some reason (possibly an artifact of NaN values), and I've decided for my use case it's easiest just to set `decode_cf=False`. The only problem is that I do actually want my `time` variable to be decoded, since some of my files have different units for time, and it's easiest to just have them all converted to `np.datetime64`.

```
dimensions:
    locations = UNLIMITED ; // (37 currently)
    time = UNLIMITED ; // (1085 currently)
variables:
    int64 locationIndex(time) ;
        locationIndex:long_name = "which location this observation is for" ;
        locationIndex:instance_dimension = "locations" ;
    float lon(locations) ;
        lon:standard_name = "longitude" ;
        lon:long_name = "location longitude" ;
        lon:units = "degrees_east" ;
        lon:valid_range = -180., 180. ;
    float lat(locations) ;
        lat:standard_name = "latitude" ;
        lat:long_name = "location latitude" ;
        lat:units = "degrees_north" ;
        lat:valid_range = -90., 90. ;
    float alt(locations) ;
        alt:standard_name = "height" ;
        alt:long_name = "vertical distance above the surface" ;
        alt:units = "m" ;
        alt:positive = "up" ;
        alt:axis = "Z" ;
    int64 location_id(locations) ;
    string location_description(locations) ;
    double time(time) ;
        time:standard_name = "time" ;
        time:long_name = "time of measurement" ;
        time:units = "days since 1970-01-01T00:00:00" ;
    int64 sat_id(time) ;
        sat_id:_FillValue = 127LL ;
        sat_id:name = "sat_id" ;
        sat_id:coordinates = "time lat lon alt" ;
    byte as_des_pass(time) ;
        as_des_pass:_FillValue = 127b ;
        as_des_pass:name = "as_des_pass" ;
        as_des_pass:coordinates = "time lat lon alt" ;
...
```

I would expect to be able to just pass `decode_cf=False` and `decode_times=True` to get `time` as a `datetime64` type, resulting in something like below:

```py
>>> a = xr.open_dataset(i_file, decode_cf=False, decode_times=True)
>>> a
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:                            (time: 1040, locations: 37)
Coordinates:
  * time                               (time) datetime64[ns] 2021-03-01T19:17...
Dimensions without coordinates: locations
Data variables: (12/34)
    locationIndex                      (time) int64 ...
    lon                                (locations) float32 ...
    lat                                (locations) float32 ...
    alt                                (locations) float32 ...
    location_id                        (locations) int64 ...
    location_description               (locations) object ...
...
```

However, instead I just get it as a float relative to my reference time:

```py
>>> a = xr.open_dataset(i_file, decode_cf=False, decode_times=True)
>>> a
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:                            (time: 1040, locations: 37)
Coordinates:
  * time                               (time) float64 1.869e+04 ... 1.872e+04
Dimensions without coordinates: locations
Data variables: (12/34)
    locationIndex                      (time) int64 ...
    lon                                (locations) float32 ...
    lat                                (locations) float32 ...
    alt                                (locations) float32 ...
    location_id                        (locations) int64 ...
    location_description               (locations) object ...
...
```

Does anybody else have this behavior or know how to solve it?

EDIT:

An example file that exhibits this behavior can be found [here](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/examples/ECMWF_ERA-40_subset.nc) (22.2 MB from Unidata):

```py
>>> import xarray as xr
>>> file = "ECMWF_ERA-40_subset.nc"
>>> ds = xr.open_dataset(file, decode_cf=False, decode_times=True)
>>> ds
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (longitude: 144, latitude: 73, time: 62)
Coordinates:
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 0.0 2.5 5.0 7.5 ... 350.0 352.5 355.0 357.5
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 90.0 87.5 85.0 82.5 ... -85.0 -87.5 -90.0
  * time       (time) int32 898476 898482 898500 898506 ... 899178 899196 899202
Data variables: (12/17)
    tcw        (time, latitude, longitude) int16 ...
    tcwv       (time, latitude, longitude) int16 ...
    lsp        (time, latitude, longitude) int16 ...
    cp         (time, latitude, longitude) int16 ...
    msl        (time, latitude, longitude) int16 ...
    blh        (time, latitude, longitude) int16 ...
    ...         ...
    e          (time, latitude, longitude) int16 ...
    lcc        (time, latitude, longitude) int16 ...
    mcc        (time, latitude, longitude) int16 ...
    hcc        (time, latitude, longitude) int16 ...
    tco3       (time, latitude, longitude) int16 ...
    tp         (time, latitude, longitude) int16 ...
Attributes:
    Conventions:  CF-1.0
    history:      2004-09-15 17:04:29 GMT by mars2netcdf-0.92
```

Comment: The first example is what I would expect to happen, I've edited to make that more clear hopefully

Comment: thank you for clarifying. Is this public data; any chance of sharing an example file? In general, I suspect time conversion is part of CF functionality; time specification (e.g. the "seconds_since_x") is CF standard. So *maybe* deactivating cf decoding deactivates this as well, however I couldn't find any info on this in [the docs](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_dataset.html)...

Comment: Not quite public data but I found some example data from Unidata that shows the same behavior, I've added it to the end of the question. You might be right about the reason but I feel the keyword is badly named if all it can do is turn OFF time decoding when CF decoding is on.

Comment: OK after digging into the code it seems decode_times eventually gets passed as an argument to the function `decode_cf`, so there's no real way to do them separately. Thankfully I found that the problem I was trying to solve by turning off `decode_cf` could actually be solved by setting `mask_and_scale` to `False`.